# Add a space after comma using VBA regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to use a regex to find cells in a range that have a comma, but no space after that comma. Then, I want to simply add a space between the comma and the next character. For example, a cell has `Wayne,Bruce` text inside, but I want to turn it to `Wayne, Bruce`.

I have a regex pattern that can find cells with characters and commas without spaces, but when I replace this, it cuts off some characters.

```
Private Sub simpleRegexSearch()
    ' adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[a-zA-Z]\,[a-zA-Z]"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ", "
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("P1:P5")

    For Each cell In Myrange
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value

            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.TEST(strInput) Then
                Debug.Print (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
            Else
                Debug.Print ("No Regex Not matched in " & cell.address)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set regEx = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I run that against "Wayne,Bruce" I get "Wayn, ruce".  How do I keep the letters, but separate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the code the following way:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "([a-zA-Z]),(?=[a-zA-Z])"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "$1, "
```

Output will be `Bruce, Wayne`.

The problem is that you cannot use a look-behind in VBScript, so we need a workaround in the form of a capturing group for the letter before the comma.

For the letter after the comma, we can use a look-ahead, it is available in this regex flavor.

So, we just capture with `([a-zA-Z])` and restore it in the replacing call with a back-reference `$1`. Look-ahead does not consume characters, so we are covered.

(EDIT) **REGEX EXPLANATION**

- `([a-zA-Z])` - A captured group that includes a character class matching just 1 English character
- `,` - Matching a literal `,` (you actually do not have to escape it as it is not a special character)
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` - A positive look-ahead that only checks (does not match, or consume) if the immediate character following the comma *is* and English letter.

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks so much! I'm just learning Regex, so will look in to the use of () and the `?=` but if you have a 'quick and dirty' explanation, it'd be more than appreciated!

Comment: @user3578951: I added some more explanation of the regex used. Mind that the comma does not have to be escaped in any regex flavor I know, I removed the escape symbol.

Comment: @user3578951 my friend Patrick Matthews wrote the best description of using regexp with VBA that I have seen [here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC4QFjABahUKEwiu_biflYTGAhVH7RQKHZ6vAPg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2Farticles%2F1336%2FUsing-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html&ei=gKx3Va69KMfaU57fgsAP&usg=AFQjCNESJKvvlJR1kTeTffUcRjzwwdNX5Q&sig2=r52YYj49aP5slGO_chXpxg&bvm=bv.95039771,d.d24)

Comment: @brettdj - thanks! I actually found that page Googling around, and it's quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If we replace all *comma*s with *comma+space* and then replace *comma+space+space* with *comma+space*, we can meet your requirement:

```
Sub NoRegex()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Range("P1:P5")
   r.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=", "
   r.Replace What:=",  ", Replacement:=", "
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, clever - that's a great way to do it as well.  Thanks!  For what it's worth: I chose the regex answer as "the" answer just because I'm trying to learn Regex too, but other than that this would work 100% just as well.

Comment: @user3578951  I agree that Regex is worth learning! ..............I tend to avoid it because others have had difficulty maintaining the regex code that I have written in the past.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - Regex looks pretty intimidating, I understand the super basics, but you can get really crazy with it, and that's where I get confused.  As I mentioned above, if you have any tips/sites/etc. that help I'm more than open to it!

Quick clarification - are regex patterns the same over all languages? I.e. would the Excel pattern above do the same thing if I was using Python, C++, Javascript, etc?

Comment: @user3578951  They are similar..........because of my lack of expertise.....I can't answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Uses the same `RegExp` as in the solution from stribizhev but with two optimisations for speed

1. Your current code sets the `RegExp` details for every cell tested, these only need setting once.
2. Looping through a varinat array is much faster than a cell range

*code*

```
Private Sub simpleRegexSearch()
    ' adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops
    Dim strPattern As String:
    Dim strReplace As String:
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim X, X1
    Dim lngnct

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    strPattern = "([a-zA-Z])\,(?=[a-zA-Z])"
    strReplace = "$1, "

    With regEx
           .Global = True
           .MultiLine = True
           .IgnoreCase = False
           .Pattern = strPattern

    X = ActiveSheet.Range("P1:P5").Value2

    For X1 = 1 To UBound(X)
            If .TEST(X(X1, 1)) Then
                Debug.Print .Replace(X(X1, 1), strReplace)
            Else
                Debug.Print ("No Regex Not matched in " & [p1].Offset(X1 - 1).Address(0, 0))
            End If
    Next
    End With

    Set regEx = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing via Regex is to find a pattern

```
(any Alphabet),(any Alphabet)
```

and then replace such pattern to

```
,_
```

where _ implies a space.

So if you have `Wayne,Bruce` then the pattern matches where `e,B`. Therefore the result becomes `Wayn, ruce`.

Try

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "([a-zA-Z]),([a-zA-Z])"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "$1, $2"
```

.